# How to avoid breaking javascript when "match" has no matches?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the following html:

```
<div id="box2">
    <p> this is some text and here is DAY 3 cool right </p>
    <!-- In the previous line, change DAY to something else -->
</div>
<br>
<select id="field"></select>
```

The following javascript correct populates the select drop down, if the regex "match" operation finds a match.  However, If I change the value of "day" to "night" the entire script stops, It does not not trigger the alert box. Is there some missing step?

```
var TextToSearch = document.getElementById('box2').innerHTML;
var result = TextToSearch.match(/DAY.*?</gi);
var select = document.getElementById("field");
if(result.length)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = i+1;
        option.innerHTML = result[i];
        select.add(option);
    }
}
alert("test");
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uooeLk2c/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Make sure you check the value of `result` before you try to get the `.length` property.

`.match` returns `null` if there is no match.

Change `if(result.length)` for `if(result !== null)`.

Comment: 1) see my answer 2) open the JavaScript console: F12 in most browsers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use *OR* `||` if there is no match. `match()` returns `null` when no match is found, then when you use `length` on `null`, error is thrown.

You can use `||` to return empty array when there is no match.

```
var result = TextToSearch.match(/NIGHT.*?</gi) || [];
```

By using this, you make sure that `result` will be always an `array` regardless of the status of `match()`.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/uooeLk2c/3/)

```js
var TextToSearch = document.getElementById('box2').innerHTML;
var result = TextToSearch.match(/DAY.*?</gi) || [];
var select = document.getElementById("field");

if (result.length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = i + 1;
    option.innerHTML = result[i];
    select.add(option);
  }
}
alert("No Error");
```

```html
<div id="box2">
  <p>this is some text and here is night 3 cool right</p>
  <!-- In the previous line, change DAY to something else -->
</div>
<br>
<select id="field"></select>
```

Comment: Removed my duplicate answer +1

Comment: what if you only ever need the second element in that array ([1]) ? I usually do `test` before match but that's too much as to me

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to check the length.

Just check if the variable exists:

`if (result) {`

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this should do...

```
if (typeof result !== 'undefined' && result && result.length)
{
/* your code here*/
}
```