# How to determine whether string is code-method?

Tags: javascript, regex

I explain my question via 2 examples:

**Example1:**

```
var str1 = "this is a test
                this is a test";
```

I want this: `this is not code-method`

**Example2:**

```
var str2 = "    this is a test

                this is a tes";
```

I want this: `this is code-method`

---

So, as you see in the above examples, if all lines start with at least 4 spaces *(in the beginning)* then it is `code-method`, else it is `not code-method`. How can I do that?

---

All I can do is counting the number of lines:

```
var text = str.val();   
var lines = text.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
var count = lines.length;
alert(count); // it is the number of lines in the string
```

Also [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/lM4pV7/2) selects all space before a newline. *(I don't know it is useful or not)*

```
/\n?\s+/gm
```

Comment: Updated your [regex](https://regex101.com/r/lM4pV7/3). It should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `/\n?\s+/gm` will select the lines that have one or more spaces at the beginning. You need to check if the line starts with four spaces.

You can use

```
/^ {4}/gm
```

[**RegEx Explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/lM4pV7/6)

1. `^`: Start of line
2. `{4}`: Match four spaces
3. `gm`: Global and multiline flag

```js
// RegEx
var linebreak = /\r\n|\r|\n/g,
    coded = /^ {4}/gm;

function isCoded(str) {
  return str.split(linebreak).length === (str.match(coded) || []).length;
}

var str1 = `    this is a test
                this is a tes`,
    str2 = ` this is test
    not coded`;

document.body.innerHTML = str1 + ': is-coded? ' + isCoded(str1) + '<br />' + str2 + ': is-coded? ' + isCoded(str2);
```

Comment: Well thanks, your regex could be a clue ..! Actually I need to determine that string is `code-method` or not ..!

Comment: Actually it should check if there are more than 4 spaces so use `{4,}`.

Comment: @noob Please check the demo, it does check that. `{4}` will match four spaces, so it does return true when the string contains more than 4 spaces at the beginning of line

Comment: @stack However the test fails because author used `\s` which allows other whitespaces too. It fails in case one gives a `newline` and then `3` spaces. [Check demo](https://regex101.com/r/lM4pV7/7)

Comment: Why you removed `,` in the `\s{4}` ? I think I need 4 spaces or more ... Am I right?

Comment: @stack There is no need of `,` in `{4}`. If the string contain `5`, `6`, `7`... spaces, it also contains 4 spaces.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but may you please tell me what are these `[` and `]`  in this `/[\r\n]/g`?

Comment: @noob You're right! Updated regex to match only ` `(space) characters.

Comment: @stack I guess that is not required. So removed.

Comment: Ok, just for my information, may you please tell me what are `[` and `]` in regex? are they define a group like `(` and `)` ?

Comment: @stack No, they both are different. `[]` are [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), `[\s\n]` will match any one of them while `(\s\n)` will match space followed by newline and add them in [captured group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: @stack Yes, also note that `[abc]+` will match a string that contains of `a`, `b`, `c` in any sequence, one or more times. I've added links in my last [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972662/how-to-determine-whether-string-is-code-method#comment57675313_34972699) it is good reference to learn regex.

Comment: Your code has this error: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null*. May you please fix it?

Comment: @stack Fixed. How? See [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32143330/2025923)

Comment: It would be better if you write `/\r\n|\r|\n/g` instead of `/\n/g` as the value of `linebreak` variable. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
> str1.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/).length == str1.match(/^\s{4,}/gm).length
< false
```

and

```
> str2.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/).length == str2.match(/^\s{4,}/gm).length
< true
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to return a boolean if you want to work out whether a string is valid or not.

You can split the string on newlines, then use the `every` method with a predicate function to test that each line meets your criteria.

```
function isCodeMethod(string) {
  const hasIndent = /^\s{4}/;
  return string
    .split("\n")
    .every(s => hasIndent.test(s));
}
```

With some test input.

```
// false
isCodeMethod("this is a test")

// true
isCodeMethod("    this is a test")

// false
isCodeMethod(`    this is a test1
this is a test2`)

// true
isCodeMethod(`    this is a test1
this is a test2`)

// true
isCodeMethod(`    this is a test1
                  this is a test2`)
```

Comment: Your code has this error: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>*. May you please fix it?

Comment: You can either use a browser that supports ES2015 arrow functions, or look at [how to translate that code back into ES5](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20isCodeMethod(string)%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20hasIndent%20%3D%20%2F%5E%5Cs%7B4%7D%2F%3B%0A%20%20return%20string%0A%20%20%20%20.split(%22%5Cn%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.every(s%20%3D%3E%20hasIndent.test(s))%3B%0A%7D).