# Replace all specific characters with counter ascending?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "some text is here
            - first case
            - second case 
            - third case
           some text is here";
```

Now I need this output:

```
var newstr = "some text is here
                1. first case
                2. second case 
                3. third case
               some text is here";
```

---

All I can do is [removing those `-`](https://regex101.com/r/jL5lB9/1). Now I need to replace `$1` with a dynamic number... Is that possible?

Something like this:

```
.replace (/(^\s*-\s+)/gm, "{A dynamic number which is ascending}. ")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) with callback and a counter.

Using ES2015 [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
str.replace(/^\s*- /gm, () => counter++ + '. ');
```

```js
var str = `some text is here
                - first case
                - second case 
                - third case
               some text is here`;

var counter = 1;
str = str.replace(/^\s*- /gm, () => counter++ + '. ');

console.log(str);
document.write(str); // Demo purpose
```

Equivalent code in ES5

```
str.replace(/^\s*- /gm, function() {
    return counter++ + '. ';
});
```

The regex `/^\s*- /gm`, will match all the lines starting with any number of spaces followed by hyphen.

```js
var str = `some text is here
            - first case
            - second case 
            - third case
           some text is here`;

var counter = 1; // Initialize the counter

str = str.replace(/^\s*- /gm, function() {
  return counter++ + '. '; // Incrementing counter after using its value
});

console.log(str);
document.write(str); // Demo purpose
```

Comment: very nice answer +++

Comment: Insane typing speed :) This much code and demo in ~2 minutes +1

Comment: I'm still waiting for the answer of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972662/how-to-determine-whether-string-is-code-method#comment-57834053) comment `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
var i=1;
while(str.indexOf("-")!=-1)
    str=str.replace(/-/,i++ +".")
```